# Google Analytics screen views has value while sessions is zero

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am creating a custom report for Behavior -> screens Report. I want to track the Screen views and sessions. I found out that for some screens, the screen has `screen views` and `unique screen views`, but the `sessions` value is zero.

[image: case]

Why does this happen? and does it make sense? 
I want to track the screen views per session and unique screen views per session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the sessions metric is only incremented once per session on the first hit of the session. I'm going to guess that the screen views where sessions is 0 are screens where the user cannot start the session with.

For your reporting needs, the unique screen views is incremented once per screen per session, thus if you want to know how many sessions viewed a particular screen, you can use that metric.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your answer correctly. You mean that the session metric is counted only for the screen where the session starts?
For example, If A session started while I'm viewing screen 1, then screen 1 sessions count will be 1, in the same session I navigated to screen to 2, then to screen 3 where another session started (let's say after 30 mins). 
Then sessions metric will show:
Screen 1 -> 1, 
Screen 2 -> 0, 
Screen 3 -> 1 ?
@XTOTHEL

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Thanks! but is there anyway to get for each screen how many screen views per session? meaning that I don't get this zero.

Comment: Unique screen views will essentially tell you how many sessions viewed this screen. If you want to know screen views per session per screen, you're essentially looking at the % of total unique screen view for this screen. Which you already have the data for from your screen shot.